# Dual Monitor Pc is slower

Tags: display, multiple-monitors, lag

I will start with my PC spec >Win 7-64bit,AMD II X4-3.20GHz,8GB(4+4) RAM,GPU-asus geforce GTX 750 Ti 2GB DDR5

Well the problem now is my PC gets slower when I use both the monitors at same time,yes I have my gpu drivers updated
but both monitors are working with different tech (one is LED and another one is LCD) and different inches...

Comment: define "my PC gets slower" in quantifiable terms.

Comment: You're not plugging one into your motherboard monitor port and one into the graphics card are you?

Comment: I hooked up both the monitors with GPU...@ArthurKay one with HDMI and another one with VGA port...

Comment: @Peter when compared to the bigger one the smaller monitor lags whlie moving a folder or file.You can see a dark shadow like thing for more than 3-5sec after moving the desired folder to a new place.,..

Comment: @Gladwin 5 seconds is about 100 times too slow. Need more info. Does the smaller monitor also lag if the bigger monitor is not connected? How are the monitors connected respectively?  What exactly is a "dark shadow like thing"?

Comment: Different backligting and different monitor sizes should not be a problem. And that card is modern enough (release around august this year) that it should drive multiple screens at a decent speed. So that is not it. Now to make sure what it is, could you check CPU usage? If that spikes to 100% for siome reason then that might be a cause. (Granted: No idea why that would happen due to a 2nd display).

Answer (score 0):

The reason why the computer runs a bit slower is that your computer is attempting to render 2 screens a the same time, which means that it is working twice as hard as far as video goes. The reason that even with your nvidia graphics you have that issue is that the nvidia card is set by default to only run under high demand, meaning that your weak, built in graphics system has more difficulty with 2 screens. Check the settings in your nvidia control panel.

Comment: That's not how a desktop computer works. The outputs on the GPU are always GPU driven. His PC has some esoteric hw/sw problem because a 750Ti should not have any issue with large numbers of monitors.

Comment: I had assumed it was a laptop. Sorry.

Comment: If i wipe and resintall new set of OS wil it work or the problem will persist @ArthurKay

Comment: If it's a software issue, yes, it likely will, but I have no guarantees.